# Writing supybot plugins not in python?

Tags: ruby, irc

What's the best way to write a supybot plugin in ruby? Or other language (not python)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, you can't. Supybot is written in Python and there is no way to load Ruby/other language module/files. Theoretically you could write the plugin in C/C++ and Supybot may attempt to load them. But you'll need to dig deep into the Python API as there are no bindings to the Supybot code.

If you prefer Ruby over Python you could use [rbot](http://www.ruby-rbot.org/) an IRC bot written in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ruby in Python via [Rython](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rython/)